# intent using images android eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent

i am building a game, the goal of the game is prevent the images to fall, what i want to happen is that when the image reaches the bottom of the screen, it will intent to a new activity .please help. i manage to make the images fall, what i want to know is how to trigger intent when the image reaches the bottom of the screen.

```
package com.example.crashthetrash;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.animation.TranslateAnimation;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class Game extends Activity {

int posy;
int posy2;
int posy3;
int posy4;
int posy5;
int posy6;
int dur;
int dur2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

      dur = 5000;
      dur2 = dur - 10;
      final ImageView chips = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.chips);

      final TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,     500.0f);
      animation.setDuration(dur);
      animation.setRepeatCount(0);
      animation.setRepeatMode(0);
      animation.setFillAfter(true);
      chips.startAnimation(animation);


      chips.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

              posy = chips.getTop();
              posy2 = 0 - posy;
              dur2 = dur2 - 10;

              TranslateAnimation animation = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, posy2, 500.0f);
              animation.setDuration(dur2);
              animation.setRepeatCount(0);
              animation.setRepeatMode(0);
              animation.setFillAfter(true);
              chips.startAnimation(animation);

            return true;
        }
    });


      final ImageView fish = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fish);

      final TranslateAnimation animation2 = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 500.0f);
      animation2.setDuration(dur);
      animation2.setRepeatCount(0);
      animation2.setRepeatMode(0);
      animation2.setFillAfter(true);
      fish.startAnimation(animation2);

      fish.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  posy3 = fish.getTop();
                  posy4 = 0 - posy;
                  dur2 = dur2 - 10;

                  TranslateAnimation animation2 = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, posy4, 500.0f);
                  animation2.setDuration(dur2);
                  animation2.setRepeatCount(0);
                  animation2.setRepeatMode(0);
                  animation2.setFillAfter(true);
                  fish.startAnimation(animation2);
                return true;
            }
        });

      final ImageView paper = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.paper);

      final TranslateAnimation animation3 = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 500.0f);
      animation3.setDuration(dur);
      animation3.setRepeatCount(0);
      animation3.setRepeatMode(0);
      animation3.setFillAfter(true);
      paper.startAnimation(animation3);


      paper.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                  posy5 = paper.getTop();
                  posy6 = 0 - posy;
                  dur2 = dur2 - 10;

                  TranslateAnimation animation3 = new TranslateAnimation(0.0f, 0.0f, posy6, 500.0f);
                  animation3.setDuration(dur2);
                  animation3.setRepeatCount(0);
                  animation3.setRepeatMode(0);
                  animation3.setFillAfter(true);
                  paper.startAnimation(animation3);
                return true;
            }
        });

      if(animation.hasEnded() || animation2.hasEnded() || animation3.hasEnded())
      {
         Intent intent = new Intent(Game.this, Restart.class);
         startActivity(intent);
      }

}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.game, menu);
    return true;
}





}
```

Comment: I think it would be easier if you used the Canvas to create your animation instead of relying on the Android built-in layout animation framework.

Comment: how am i going to do that sir? i am new in eclipse so i am not that familiar.

Comment: another thing, i can click the image and the animation ill restart, but when the image is halfway the screen from falling, i cannot click it anymore. why is that happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(animation.hasEnded())
{
   Intent myIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
   CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(myIntent);
}
```

Comment: i tried it sir but it does not work, it has no errors but when i run it, the image just keep on falling.

Comment: if(animation.hasEnded())
    {
       Intent myIntent = new Intent(Game.this, Restart.class);
       Game.this.startActivity(myIntent);
    }

Comment: Well, I think that those two lines       `animation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
      animation.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);` are the reason why it keeps running...

Comment: i cahnged it to 1, it still did not intent.

Comment: `if(animation.hasEnded() || animation2.hasEnded() || animation3.hasEnded())
    {
       Intent change = new Intent(Game.this, Restart.class);
       startActivity(change);
    }`

Comment: above is my code. it does not do anything. i made my repeataccount and repeatmode 0

Comment: i posted the whole class, please take a look. thanks. :D

Answer (score 2):

```
     if(animation.hasEnded() || animation2.hasEnded() || animation3.hasEnded())
  {
     Intent intent = new Intent(Game.this, Restart.class);
     startActivity(intent);
  }
```

Should be outside the click listener.

Comment: it is outside the touch listener sir.

Comment: Does it trigger the next activity ?

Comment: it does not, nothing happenss, when the image reach the bottom, it just stop there.

Comment: Doest fish or paper has .hasEnded() method?

Comment: what do you mean? it all have .hasEnded() method. man, this problem makes me ill. thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: Change  `if(animation.hasEnded() || animation2.hasEnded() || animation3.hasEnded())
  {
     Intent intent = new Intent(Game.this, Restart.class);
     startActivity(intent);
  }`

to 

`if(fish.hasEnded() || paper.hasEnded())
  {
     Intent intent = new Intent(Game.this, Restart.class);
     startActivity(intent);
  }`

Comment: what should i put in there?

Comment: it have errors,. fish, paper are the name of my imageview, not the animations. it recommends me to cast the fish or paper.

Comment: Arg, and why did you start twice the animations?

Comment: one will generate when the activity load, the other i5 when the image i5 clicked.

Answer (score 1):

TranslateAnimation inherit from animation object and has a boolean "hasEnded()" so you can test this value and trigger you new intent.

Comment: how am i going to do that sir? i am new in eclipse so i am not that familiar.  thanks.

Comment: another thing, i can click the image and the animation ill restart, but when the image is halfway the screen from falling, i cannot click it anymore. why is that happening?